# Is it possible to have XStream skip a null element in an array?

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xstream

If I have an `Object[]` with the size of, let say, `8`, and the 4th element is null, is it possible to call `toXML()` and have it not return an XML with the 4th element which is null?